# How to authenticate with SSC REST API using Item service auth

Tags: sitecore-services-client, itemservice

I've been trying to use Sitecore SSC REST API to create an item. I can login, but that is as far as I get - every other request (even to get an item) returns forbidden.

I've already changed the  `Sitecore.Services.SecurityPolicy` to `ServicesOnPolicy`.

I also don't quite understand how it authenticates the subsequent requests (no api key). I thought it used cookies. The login returns 4 cookies and I have tried using the one that makes sense but still no luck.

Does anyone had success with the API to get item or create item?

The only success I had was by allowing anonymous User. I have also set `sitecore/serviceAPI` as administrator.

Comment: I had the security policy setup properly and the request going properly too, but it turns out i had some rewrite rules that were redirecting my login auth, resulting in not getting the right cookies back. You are supposed to get a AspNet.Cookies back and use that token, and i wasn't getting that one back. Removed that rewrite rule and now works fine. FYI Sitecore 9.2

Answer (score 3):

It’s a bit hard to know what’s going on without seeing your code and config and knowing your Sitecore version but some things to check are:

**Login Cookies**

Are you getting the login cookies from the login endpoint and passing the login cookies in your request to the API? Here is an example of a get item request. The login cookies are created by a separate request which I’ve not included the code for.

```
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.CreateHttp($"https://{_baseAPIUrl}/sitecore/api/ssc/item/{HttpUtility.UrlEncode(parentItemId)}/children?includeStandardTemplateFields=true");
            request.Method = "GET";
            request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data";
            request.CookieContainer = loginCookies;

            using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(stream))
                    {
                        string responseContent = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }
```

**Security Policy**

Check your security policy setting is correct. I’d recommend the following which allows remote requests:

```
<settings>
    <setting name="Sitecore.Services.SecurityPolicy">
        <patch:attribute name="value" value="Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.Web.Http.Security.ServicesOnPolicy, Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure" />
    </setting>
</settings>
```

**The API Docs for 9.0 are here:**

https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/sitecore-experience-manager/en/the-restful-api-for-the-itemservice.html